# How to read sql query to pandas dataframe / python / django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using this below in **views.py** to get app

```
from django.db import connection

def test(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = """
    SELECT x , n
    from table1 limit 10
    """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,cursor)  <==> not working ) 
    # df1.columns = cursor.keys()    <==> not working ) 

    return render(request, 'app/test.html',{ "row" : rows,})
```

I am able to print row and got a list of something like this below in **test.html**

```
row((x1,yvalue1),(x2,yvalue2) , .... ))
```

But what I'm trying to do is to get all data with its column name that I fetched and put into dataframe , hopefully to use something like this below :

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query

Comment: I don't know anything about django, but i believe the only 'native' connection you can use with read_sql_query is for sql lite.  You need to use sql alchemy for all others.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think aus_lacy is a bit off in his solution - first you have to convert the `QuerySet` to a string containing the SQL backing the `QuerySet`

```
from django.db import connection

query = str(ModelToRetrive.objects.all().query)
df = pandas.read_sql_query(query, connection)
```

Also there is a less memory efficient but still valid solution:

```
df = DataFrame(list(ModelToRetrive.objects.values('id','some_attribute_1','some_attribute_2')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Django's built in `QuerySet API`. More information on it can be seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/). Once you create a `QuerySet` you can then use pandas `read_sql_query` method to construct the data frame. The simplest way to construct a `QuerySet` is simply query the entire database which can be done like so:

```
db_query = YourModel.objects.all()
```

You can use filters which are passed in as args when querying the database to create different `QuerySet` objects depending on what your needs are.

Then using pandas you could do something like:

```
d_frame = pandas.read_sql_query(db_query, other_args...)
```