# Django database connection library issue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oracle, pandas

I faced this behavior, not sure it's a bug. When I use connection created from `cx_Oracle`, It is working as assumed. 
But when I use `Django DB connections`, It is giving result but not as expected.

```
import cx_Oracle
from django.db import connections
import pandas as pd

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xx.x.xx.xxx', 'port', 'dbname')
cx_Oracle_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', dsn_tns)

django_conn = connections["DB2"] # In django settings, I have a created "DB2" and passed the same parameters.

query = ''' 
SELECT (T1.ACCEPTED- T2.CANCELLED) AS "NET" FROM
(
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) AS ACCEPTED FROM ACCEPTED_TABLE
GROUP BY ID
) T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, COUNT(1) AS CANCELLED FROM CANCELLED_TABLE
GROUP BY ID) T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID
'''

df1 = pd.read_sql(query, cx_Oracle_conn) # Gives right result
df2 = pd.read_sql(query, django_conn) # Gives only count of T1.ACCEPTED(T2.CANCELLED having 0 count)
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the reason for this? How a connection can effect the execution of query?
2. Is it a bug of Django? Or Do I need to use django connections in other way?
3. How `django.db.backends.oracle` this works? Can explain in detail?

**Versions:**

Django == 2.1.2

Python == 3.6.7

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle' # As mentioned in django document in DB connections
```

Comment: Are you sure, `DB2` points to the same place than `cx_Oracle_conn`?

Comment: @trinchet Yes, I have given same credentials for both connections. And `DB2` is DATABASE name provided in `settings.py` file. In general, I use the django connections. After facing this wired issue, I tried with normal procedure for connection.

Comment: Are other queries returning unexpected results against the django connection, or just the one in the original post?  To triple-check that both connections are pointing to the same place, you could change the query to this: `SELECT user||';'||SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_NAME')||';'||SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST') from dual;` Also, this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28693089/11611377 suggests a different method of populating the DataFrame using read_sql_query and a QuerySet rather than read_sql.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @cdub No, Django connection is working fine for other queries. Only for original post it is returning unexpected results. And I have also checked from idle by passing same parameters and to both connections. I got same unexpected results. In the link, django has models. But in my case I didn't created any models. So, I already have a query as string. And I have also tried with `read_sql_query`(No use).

Comment: It would be helpful to see whether the SQL that's being parsed by Oracle differs between the two connections.  You can usually use the v$session and v$sql views to find the parsed queries - or work with your DBA to trace your sessions.  If the SQL is the same between the two, then I'm out of ideas.